# how can I find the whole code of an application that is already on google play

Tags: android

If I like an application in android,is there a method to know the process they made it? like for a website 'view source code' gives us the whole code of the page. In the same way can I find the code for an application in android

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within scope as defined in the Help Center. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot look at the source of an Android app without additional steps.  It is possible to decompile the Java Code, and there are tools for this.

Bottom line, there is no simple way to look at source, this is different than a Web page, as the code is compiled into an application and deployed.

Answer (score 2):

You should'nt try to **pirate** someone else's code.
You could try to reverse engineer their app using specialized tools, but this is **illegal**.
And you would get some **hardly readable** piece of code.

You can **figure out** (great exercise) how they achieved a certain result or interface design.
You might also want to try searching for a **similar** app which is **open source** (so to study what they did).

You could even ask an **experienced developer** to help you understand the app mechanics (at least in macro blocks). Once you have the blocks, you go `top-down` (this approach is called **divide et impera**) and study how each of them works, in order to build what you have in mind as if you were playing with LEGOs.

Or you can **contact the author** and ask them if they give you some code snippet.
You might have to **pay a fee**, though.

Comment: sorry.. I dint mean to pirate some ones code. there are some apps which really impressed me.. just wanted to know how they made it.. thats it. no other intentions :)

Comment: Well, my best advice is: 1 - Try to figure out yourself. 2 - Search for similar apps in the open source. 3 - Ask the original developers for some advice

Answer (score 1):

### No, you can't.

The only way to have the code is if the author publishes the code (as open source or via their own/third-party website).